# Simple Java countdown timer

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I'm working on a school project in Java and need to figure out how to create a timer.
The timer I'm trying to build is supposed to count down from 60 seconds.

Comment: Console? GUI? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried; this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513) may be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
 int i = 60;
 while (i>0){
  System.out.println("Remaining: "i+" seconds");
  try {
    i--;
    Thread.sleep(1000L);    // 1000L = 1000ms = 1 second
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
       //I don't think you need to do anything for your particular problem
   }
 }
```

Or something like that

EDIT, i Know this is not the best option, otherwise you should create a new class:

### Correct way to do this:

```
public class MyTimer implements java.lang.Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runTimer();
    }

    public void runTimer(){
        int i = 60;
         while (i>0){
          System.out.println("Remaining: "+i+" seconds");
          try {
            i--;
            Thread.sleep(1000L);    // 1000L = 1000ms = 1 second
           }
           catch (InterruptedException e) {
               //I don't think you need to do anything for your particular problem
           }
         }
    }

}
```

Then you do in your code:
    Thread thread = new Thread(MyTimer);

Comment: I tried your method, and it worked, except that i "paused" every thing else in the program until it was done. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: In order to do so, you would need to run this method in a new Thread, but we don't want to make things too complicated, i added new code in the original answer.

Comment: It still pauses, when i press the start button the button don't even go up until the timer is done!

Comment: added the correct way, or at least how i would do this, you need to create a new class for your timer, it has to implements Runnable, and the run method, i separated the timer function, and it's called when this new class is invoked when you call new Thread(MyTimer);, check it and let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Here's how it looks right know: http://piclair.com/351ak and http://piclair.com/14tw4

Comment: odd, are you importing the class?
like, "import [location]MyTimer;"? (be sure to replace [location] with the package name where "MyTimer" is located, it may be the default package so you should do "import MyTimer;" in that case), check the little error icon at the left of the screen to see a hint

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide specifics, this would work if you don't need it to be perfectly accurate.

```
for (int seconds=60 ; seconds-- ; seconds >= 0)
{
    System.out.println(seconds);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: For those of you that got 'Not a statement' Error, re-arrange the code to:

`for (int seconds = 60; seconds >= 0; seconds--)`

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: With a bad question like this, I find this so-so answer to be the best general answer. A simple example use would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Consider using a sleep function and have it sleep 1 second between each iteration and display the seconds left.

Answer (score 0):

**It is simple to countdown with Java. Lets say you want to countdown 10 min so Try this.**

```
            int second=60,minute=10;
            int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      second--;
      // put second and minute where you want, or print..
      if (second<0) {
          second=59;
          minute--; // countdown one minute.
          if (minute<0) {
              minute=9;
          }
      }
  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```