# Automatically close non-modal dialogs after specified time in swing 1.5

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jdialog

In Swing for Java 1.5 I want to create a dialog, which allows the user to do other things in background. I want this dialog to have one button, with which you can close the dialog. If the user doesn't close the dialog within X seconds, it should close itself. In both cases a routine has to be done after the dialog has been closed.

I tried to use Swing Timer with a modal dialog and it works. But, as I noticed above, I need a non-modal dialog. When I set the modal-Property to false, the dialog disappears immediately.

Does someone know, why this happens?

```
JOptionPane pane =  new JOptionPane (text, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
pane.setOptions(new String[]{"Close"});
final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(frame, title);
//dialog.setModal(false);

Timer timer = new Timer(time, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        dialog.setVisible(false);
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();

dialog.setVisible(true);

//routine to do after the dialog disappears
```

Comment: Your code works for me, either set to modal or non-modal. Maybe something wrong with the rest of your code?

Comment: Same as Rempelos, tested your code with and without setting the dialog modal and it works. Something else than what you showed us is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you tried this with Java 1.5?

Comment: I tried with the execution environment in 1.5 with jdk1.6.0_33, don't have the 1.5 installed.

Answer (score 2):

1. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), there no code or descriptions about `MultiThreading`
2. don't create `final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(frame, title);` on runtime, create this `JDialog` one time and re_use that for another action, and / or by removing all childs from `ContentPane`
3. override proper event from [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html), there you can invoke your custom code before `dipose()`, `setVisible()` e.i.
4. (to point 2nd.) simply to override [JDialog#setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`
5. all code that invoking a new `Top-Level Container` on runtime must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, especially `setVisible(true)`
6. use [Application Inactivity by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/)

Comment: The example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694503/230513) uses a `JOptionPane` directly in a modeless dialog.

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513), a modeless `JDialog` containing a [*direct* `JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) counts down to zero before closing. A nearby `JFrame` containing a label remains responsive.

Addendum: As @mKorbel helpfully comments, your class can use a `PropertyChangeListener` to learn when the dialog's option pane closes. This is a convenient [feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) of `JOptionPane`, but you can add your own support, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).

[image]

Comment: aaach now I can to seeeeee `//routine to do after the dialog disappears`

Comment: Good point! I [buried the lead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bury_the_lead); more above.