# How to temporary disable the OK button on JOptionPane input dialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

My question is how to temporary disable the OK button on JOptionPane input dialog until a key is pressed?

Comment: It isn't possible with JOptionPane, but it is possible with a `JDialog` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Comment: We need more info. Are you using default dialogs (JOptionPane.showXXXXDialog) or are making you own dialog?

Comment: Maybe you can see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup. It explain how to validate user input by adding a listener and checking values before closing the dialog. In your case, validating may consist in check if the input is the key that you are searching for.

Comment: JOptionDialog is a ready-to-use class with a limited set of configuration options. One solution would be to display the dialog again after the user presses OK. Bit otherwise you need to make your own dialog using the JDialog class. There is a nice tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: This is not true. See my answer.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad You are still core-coding the components of the pane. I think the OP meant with the default JOptionPane.

Comment: You can add a `JOptionPane` to a `JDialog`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228911/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
JPanel pan = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
final JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
final JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
ok.setEnabled(false);

ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String input = txt.getText();
        System.out.println("The input is: " + input);

        /* close the dialog */
        Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ok);
        if(w != null) w.setVisible(false);
    }
});

txt.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
{
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getDocument().getLength() == 0) ok.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getDocument().getLength() > 0) ok.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){}
});

pan.add(txt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, pan, "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new JButton[]{ok}, ok);
```