# How to code custom JOptionPane button?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a few questions regarding `JOptionPane` class. Why does the `JOptionPane` custom buttons quit by default? For example, if i click on clear, why does the program close and not clear the textfield and stay still? Also, if i click on add or retrieve data to/from file, why does the program closes? Why don't they react like `JButtons` on a frame?

Could you please show me an example of how to clear or go to previous form without the window closing down.

Code:

```
String[] buttons = new String[] {"Add", "Clear", "Previous Window", "Retrieve"};
int example = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(mypanel, mypanel, "Choose", 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, buttons , buttons [0]);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the tutorial article [*Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup), which illustrates using a `PropertyChangeListener` to override the default behavior. This [`JOptionTimeTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513) is a related example.