# Closing the Frame when the timer expires

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am a beginner, and I am developing an Online Test in Java.

I have timer in the code. Assume the test time to be 60 seconds. After expiry of the time I have to show the result frame (Actually I have 10 frames for 10 questions and a result frame).

How do I set the visiblity of the opened frame at the instant of expiry to false?

Comment: Start with with [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) then take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and you might find [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because multiple frames are [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice), use a dialog. In this [`JOptionTimeTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513), a `JOptionPane` is embedded in a `JDialog` to allow submitting manually before the timer expires. Note the dispatch of a `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING` event to close the dialog.

[image]