# Dialog box that disappear automatically

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, windowlistener

I am developing a application. I want when I exit it, a message box appears having message, for example, "Thanks for using Soft Attendance". Then disappear automatically say after few seconds.
I have write code for this as following:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        int whichOption;
        whichOption=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f1,"Are you Serious?","Soft Attendence",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(whichOption==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            f1.dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thanks for using Soft Attendence");
        }
    }
```

When i click on exit button a confirmation dialog box appear and after clicking yes button
application is exited and a another message box appears.

```
Now I have two questions in my mind :
```

First question is I have dispose application already and then message box is shown. **Is it fine to show message box after its parent is killed?** 
When second message box appears I don't want to click on "OK" button. I want it should automatically disappear. So my second question is **How to shown message box that disappear automatically after some time?**

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513).

Answer (score 1):

```
Is it fine to show message box after its parent is killed?
```

I think this would not be a ideal case. But you can open dialog if the parentComponent has no Frame `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"...");`

```
How to shown message box that disappear automatically after some time?
```

Auto disposable you can get it by a trick, you can create a `SwingWorker` which normally performs GUI-interaction tasks in a background thread. Set a timer and which will execute after time period and close your dialog explicitly.

```
class AutoDisposer extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Object> {
   @Override
   public String doInBackground() {
       try{
           JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
           return Boolean.True;
       }catch(Exception ex){...}
       return Boolean.False;
   }
}
```

...

```
new Timer(seconds * 1000, autoDisposer).start();
```

Comment: JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose(); must be wrapped into invokeLater, doInBackground() executing Workers Thread, never notified EDT

Comment: Thanks....but i have done it in other way,that by first hiding app ,then showing dialog box after waiting sometime with Thread.sleep(), then disposing the app....