# JDialog with Modality set to Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS : optionPane.getValue() not working anymore

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, modality

i have an application, where I need to work on a **frame**, while I want to have a dialog open.

So I set the modality to `Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS`. While this enables me to interact with the parent JFrame, I cannot use the `getValue()` anymore on the dialog.

Here is a running minimal example:

```
package Test;

 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import javax.swing.JDialog;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class TestModalityDialog {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    String[] options = new String[]{"Hello"};
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(
            "Click on a cluster to delete it (needs to be confirmed by pressing the 'Confirm' button.");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(
            "Press 'p' to undelete an unconfirmed deletion.");
    Object complexMsg[] = { label1, label2 };
    optionPane.setMessage(complexMsg);
    optionPane.setOptions(options);
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(frame,
            "Select undesired clusters");
    //dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS); //uncomment this line out
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.setVisible(false);//must be set to false for Modality to work
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    Object obj = optionPane.getValue();
    int result = -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < options.length; k++) {
        if (options[k].equals(obj)) {
            result = k;
        }
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        System.out.println("Succesful");
    }

}

 }
```

The system out works here, when you press the button labeled "Hello". Put you cannot interact with the frame behind. If you uncomment

```
//dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
```

this will allow "interaction" (not in this minimal example ofc), but I dont get a system out anymore.

Second thing which I did not expect is that you have to press the button two times in the uncommented version to work.

For help I would be gladful, already tried out the other 3 modalitie values, but the did not work.

Cheers,
Buddha

Comment: See examples shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513).

Comment: Thanks, Propertylistener works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Communication with a *modeless* dialog can be accomplished using a `PropertyChangeEvent`, either an existing one, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451673/230513), of one of you own, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).