# java joptionpane which automatically closes after few seconds

Tags: java, swing, popup, joptionpane

Help needed for making a popup which automatically closes after a few seconds. JOptionpane messages usually needs an input to close, so is there any other way to handle auto-closing popup in java. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12448947/230513).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the option pane can be modeless, this might be one way to do it:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AutoCloseJOption {

    private static final int TIME_VISIBLE = 3000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("My App");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(100, 100);
        frame1.setLocation(100, 100);

        JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
        frame1.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
                dialog.setModal(false);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

                new Timer(TIME_VISIBLE, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        frame1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

For this example, press the button and an option dialog will be visible for three seconds.

Comment: The `TimerTask` callback is incorrectly synchronized; use `javax.swing.Timer`, as shown in either duplicate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated the example to use javax.swing.Timer